# R help. I'm running a Simple Gibbs Sampler for mu and sig^2 for normal data using informative non-conjugate priors

Tags: r, bayesian

Mu is distributed as N(0,1) and sig^2 is distributed as IGamma(a,b) with a = 1, b = 2. I'm trying to create a couple of graphs (histograms, scatterplots, ACF, PACF) but keep getting error messages of "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ"

It's probably a stupid question but I'm new to r. This is the program I've ran so far

```
# Gibbs sampler, MODEL 2: semi-conjugate normal model

#
#  Density of inverse gamma distribution
#dinvgamma = function( x, shape, rate ) 
{
   exp( shape * log( rate ) - lgamma( shape ) -( shape+1)*log(x) - rate/x )
}

nn = 200
yy = rnorm( nn, 1, 4 )

mu.0 = 1.0

sig2.0 = 4^2

a = 2

b = 1

M = 10000

mu   = rep( 0, 10000 )
sig2 = rep( 1, 10000 )

mean.y = mean( yy )
var.y = var( yy )

mu[1]   = mean.y
sig2[1] = var.y 


for( ii in 2:M ) {

   mu.star <- ((1/sig2.0)*mu.0 + (nn/sig2 [ii-1])*mean(yy))/((1/sig2.0)+(nn/sig2 [ii-          1]))

   sig2.star <- 1/((1/sig2.0)+(nn/sig2[ii-1]))


   # sample mu from its full cond.
   #
   mu[ii] = rnorm( 1, mu.star, sqrt( sig2.star ))

   a.star <-  a + (nn/2)

   b.star <- (sum((yy-mu [ii])^2)/2) + b

   # sample sig2 from its full cond.
   #
   sig2[ii] = 1 / rgamma( 1, a.star, rate = b.star )

## print( c( mu[ii], sig2[ii] ))
}

mu <- mu[9001:length(mu)]
sig2  <-  sig2[9001:length(mu)]

#
# Time series
#
 par(mfrow=c(2,2))

 plot( 1:M, mu, type="l", xlab="Iteration", xlim=c(0, 50), ylim=c(0, 100),
       main= "Mu" )

 hist( mu, prob = T )
 x = seq( min(mu), max( mu ), len=200 )
 lines( x, dnorm( x, mean=mu.0, sd=sqrt(sig2.0) ), col=2, lwd=2)

 acf( mu )

 pacf( mu )

#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
par(new=TRUE)
 par(mfrow=c(2,2))

 plot( 1:M, sig2, type="l", xlab="Iteration", ylab="sig^2",xlim=c(0, 50), ylim=c(0,      100), main= "sig^2" )

 hist( sig2, prob = T )
 x = seq( 0, max( sig2 ), len=200 )
 lines( x, dinvgamma( x,  shape=a, rate=b ), col=2, lwd=2)

 acf( sig2 )

 pacf( sig2 )
 par(new=TRUE)
plot(mu, sig2, main="Scatterplot Example", xlim=c(0, 50), ylim=c(0, 100),xlab="mu ",     ylab="sig2 ", pch=19)
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I'm under no illusion that my code is efficient or even approaching it so any changes you may deem necessary please feel free to tell me

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be coming from redefining these two variables:

```
mu <- mu[9001:length(mu)]
sig2  <-  sig2[9001:length(mu)]
```

I commented them out and the script ran fine producing the plot (presumably) as desired. Maybe take a look at how you are redefining `mu` and `sig2`

Comment: Thank you, that has freed it up straight away

Comment: One more question about this program, I'm having trouble inputting the main data into r. This program is sampling from a non-conjugate distribution of (N(1, 4^2), N(0,1), IG(2,1)) I get that I need to code this in but is it the product or is there something else? I'm entering it like this:

Comment: #
# Posterior predictive density ( ppd[1:lx] )for data on the grid x
#
lx = 200
x = seq( min(yy) - .1*(max(yy) - min(yy)), 
         max(yy) + .1*(max(yy) - min(yy)), len = lx )

dev.new()
hist( yy, prob=T )

ppd = rep( 0, lx )

for( ii in 1:lx )
{
   ##### enter the code here
   ### ppd[ ii ] = mean( dnorm( .....
}

lines( x, ppd, col=2, lwd=2 )

## postscript("fig1.ps", pointsize=20)
## dev.off()                                                        I think that I'm getting closer but I'm not sure. I understand that I'm not sampling from the product of distributions but not sure where to go

Comment: This might be better as a separate question